# Error: Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.KeyState' does not contain a definition for 'GetPressedKeys'

Tags: c#, xna

All. I want to write an input text box in with C# and XNA. Here is my code:

```
//Get the pressed key and show them
 public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
      {
            KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
            Keys[] pressedKeys;
            pressedKeys = KeyState.GetPressedKeys();

            messageString=" ";

            for (int i = 0; i < pressedKeys.Length; i++)
                messageString = messageString + pressedKeys[i].ToString() + "";

      }
```

However, I got the error message like

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.KeyState' does not contain a definition for 'GetPressedKeys'
```

Is there any way to fix it please?

UPDATE: I have typo here. Using following answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pressedKeys = KeyState.GetPressedKeys(); should be pressedKeys = keyState.GetPressedKeys();

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Sure thing kingdamina42. It was a typo. The method GetPressedKeys doesn't exist in the enumerator Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.KeyState. It does exist in the structure KeyboardState retrieved from Keyboard.GetState(); and placed in variable keyState